# How to avoid CSS in parent page

Tags: html, css

I am using Bootstrap Modal Plugin

```
$("#summaryFileDisplay").html(data.summaryfileContent);
$("#myModal").modal("show");
```

In above code **data.summaryfileContent** contains html and css data which i am rendering into **summaryFileDisplay** id

Modal rendering is fine, but it make changes in the parent CSS as well.

How can i avoid the same

Comment: The css cascade workflow should prevent this, I guess you are using ID and class selectors, aren't you?

Comment: you can set a different id for the body on every page example `<body id="page1">` then in css it goes like `#page1 div #modal { background: red;` only working in that specific page even if the same stylesheet is shared by all pages;

Comment: Could you show data.summaryfileContent ?

Answer (score 0):

Add .modal-dialog before all the styles rendering in modal. So it will make styles exclusive for Bootstrap dialogs.

```
/*
e.g.
Current CSS code.*/
.lineBorder {
    border: solid 1px #000;
}

/*Change above to*/
.modal-dialog .lineBorder {
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
```